# How do i put some database fields on an edit text field for edit purpose?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table and at the very end of the row i put for each user a button for edit , when i click edit button a popup activates and i want to put the user1 for example info for each field to be easier to edit .

I don't know how to import from database the values for each user and that makes it harder . I really need help on this typescript part , its really hard for me to understand.

Dialogs ts :

```
export class DialogEditPatientComponent implements OnInit {
action:string;
local_data:any;
form : FormGroup;
patientDetails : PatientDetails;
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogEditPatientComponent>,
//@Optional() is used to prevent error if no data is passed
@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: PatientDetails, private 
formBuilder : FormBuilder) { 
  console.log(data);
this.local_data = {...data};
this.action = this.local_data.action;
}
doAction(){
  this.dialogRef.close({event:this.action,data:this.form.value});
}

closeDialog(){
  this.dialogRef.close({event:'Cancel'});
}

ngOnInit() {
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  cnp:['', [Validators.required]],
  firstName:['', [Validators.required]],
  lastName:['', [Validators.required]],
  birthDate:[new Date(), [Validators.required]],
  phoneNumber:[''],
  city:[''],
  country:[''],
  sex:['', [Validators.required]]
}

)}
```

Where the method is implemented on the button :

```
openEditDialog(action, obj) {
obj.action = action;
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogEditPatientComponent, {
  width: '250px',
  data: obj
});


dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
 if (result.event == 'Update') {
    this.updateRowData(result.data);
  } 
});
}

updateRowData(data: any) {
this.patientRestService.editPatient(data)
  .subscribe(succes => {
    this.dataSource
  })
 }
```

Comment: If I'm getting your point you want to edit one row from table. if problem is this than you are not need to get data for user because you have already data in data table get one row and pass them to dialog.

Comment: @Abhishek how do i do that sir ? Can u give me an example please ?

Comment: can you  plz share code in `stackblitz`

Comment: @Abhishek sure  https://angular-srrrck.stackblitz.io

Comment: @Abhishek did u see it ?